On the subtraction of sum of cosines
Consider two multisets $A$ and $B$ with $k$ integer values on each them, but with empty intersection. Those values can be taken between $0$ and $n-1$. That is $A,B\subset\{0,\ldots,n-1\}^{[k]}$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$. The elements of $A$ and $B$ will be called $A_i$ and $B_i$ for the $i$-th element. For example, we can consider for $k=6$ and $n=8$, $A=(1,1,3,5,5,6)$ and $B=(0,2,2,2,2,7)$.
Further consider the following polynomial:
$$p(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^k cos(\theta A_i)-\sum_{i=1}^k cos(\theta B_i).$$
My question is: Is there a choice of multisets $A$ and $B$ satisfying the hypothesis such that $p(\theta)=0$ for every $\theta$?

No. Suppose we have that $p$ is the zero function. For any $m\in \mathbb{N}$, take the $4m$-th derivative of $p$ at $\theta=0$, this must equal zero. This yields the equation
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k}A_i^{4m}-\sum_{i=1}^kB_i^{4m}=0
$$
As $m\to\infty$, the largest term from $A\cup B$ will dominate the above expression. But then the expression cannot be equal to $0$, as the maximum is only contained in either $A$ or $B$ (the left side would either go to $\infty$ if the maximum is in $A$ or otherwise to $-\infty$). So we conclude that such a $p$ cannot exist.

Very good idea to use the derivative at 0. Thanks for the answer.
